was to be finished / was to have been finished

The construction of the bridge ( ) finished today, but as the builders have been on strike the bridge is only half finished.
A. will be
B. is
C. was to be
D. was to have been

The given answer is D.  But I want to argue that C is also possible. The only difference is, with D, the first half of the sentence alone tells us the bridge hasn't been finished, whereas with c, the sentence doesn't tell us whether the bridge is finished today until the last half. "To be finished" only shows what the plan was, but it still makes sense, I think.

I can see (in my mind at least) you could argue C or D, but I think within that sentence (to me at least) C is more about the bridge and implies it's almost finished, only slight delay, but D is more about the date (today). However I think a better fit would be 'would have been' or 'should have been' or even 'was originally going to be' (as BrE speaker)

Careless tests often give multiple choice answers of which more than one could be valid. The test taker is then supposed to rack their brains over which one is the better answer, but perhaps it would better if the test makers were more careful.

I’m voting to close this question because it's about a low-quality "multiple choice answer" test, not worth bothering with.

@AndyBonner: It's not impossible to envisage contexts where A is a valid choice. For example, just continue the cited utterance with ...so we're gonna have to work really hard this afternoon to make sure we finish before knocking off.

@FumbleFingers The second clause strongly suggests that this statement is being made at the end of the day, so it's too late for "will be" to be correct.

We look at a simpler pair in a different situation:
C1. The construction of the bridge is to be finished today.
D1. The construction of the bridge was to have been finished today, but ...
C1 is used in a morning briefing.
D1 is used at the end of the day to tell the team they've missed the target.
For the OP’s example,
(C) was to be is possible in a shortened sentence:
The construction of the bridge was to be finished today.
(D) was to have been is needed for the full sentence:
The construction of the bridge was to have been finished today, but as the builders have been on strike the bridge is only half finished.
